# Python scrape webpage after POST to get url not present in the page source

Tags: python, html, post, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Basically I want to download mp3 from youtube thanks to this online conversion service.

```
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/it
```

You fill in the form with the youtube video url to convert and you get a page with the download link.

The html form is something like this:

```html
<div id="form">
        <form method="get" action="/" id="submit-form">
              <input type="text" id="youtube-url" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE" onclick="sAll(this)" autocomplete="off" />
            <div id="btns">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Converti il video" disabled="disabled" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

After the conversion the page looks like this:
[image]

I want to be able to programmatically retrieve the download link from python. (I want to retrieve the link pointing to "Scarica" in the image, Italian for "download")

If I see the HTML source of this new page I don't see anything interesting, because link is not present.

(QUESTION in the QUESTION: why is the link not present in the source? )

Can you please provide some code to do this?
I've already accomplished my goal using Selenium, but this time I want to exclusively do it with python.

Code should do these things:

1 POST the youtube video url to convert to the page.

2 get the download link

3 download the mp3

I already know the BeautifulSoup library for parsing.

Thanks.

Comment: In your developper console, look at the 2 "GET" requests that this website is doing when you submit the form. You can do what you want requesting this 2 urls (with urllib2 for exemple).

Comment: It seems necessary to implement part of the javascript code in python to create the GET url, including a function to supply a strange parameter named 's'.